# Correctly sorting doubles with JTable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a table where the first column contains Strings and the second contains doubles.

```
    stars = new StarDatabase(path);
    Object[][] data = new Object[stars.size()][2];
    int i = 0;
    for (String name : stars.keySet()) {
        data[i][0] = name;
        data[i++][1] = stars.get(name).period;
    }
    StarsTable = new JTable(data, StarsColumnNames);
    StarsTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

The doubles are sorted as strings, so 1 < 15 < 2 < 25 < 3. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to this is found in [*How to Use Tables—Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). Just make sure your second column actually contains [`Double`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) values. Either of the available [`valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) methods may be used to make the type explicit.

Answer (score 1):

A few very good hints [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1100__JTable-Sort.htm)!

Answer (score 1):

Try using GlazedList .. it just invloves few line of code and very neat .[Glazedlist](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/)

---