# JTable double formatting

Tags: java, swing, format

I have a JTable with a doubles column. Most of them are of the form x.xxx. Some of them end with a 0 and that is omitted, so I have a right-aligned table that looks like

```
1.339
 1.34
1.353
...
```

Any way to pad 0s to the end of it, or make it align by decimal place, or anything along those sorts? I would just assign them to strings and pad 0s that way, but then I would have the problem of String comparison (1 < 15 < 2 < 25 < 3).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correctly sorting doubles with JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273353/correctly-sorting-doubles-with-jtable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use a renderer as suggested by fd, theres an example [here](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-control-decimal-places-displayed-in-jtable-column)

Answer (score 5):

I think a custom `TableCellRenderer` might be what you want.

Here's an example:

http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-control-decimal-places-displayed-in-jtable-column

You should be able to modify it for your needs.